# Integer solution to the equation below

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, education

I wanted to know integer solutions to the equation

```
(1/k1) + (10/k2) + (100/k3) + ..... + (10^18/k19) = 1 (where k1,k2,k3.... are integers)
```

which I believe is unique and exists.
I tried for n=1 ... k1=1;
I tried for n=2 ... k1=6,k2=12;
k1=11 and k2=11 are also possible but I needed k1 not equal to k2.
Plz correct me if anyone proves that it is not necessary for the solution to exist and be unique (including the condition k1!=k2!=k3!=k4......)

Comment: n is the number of terms in the equation.....the final equation has n=19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions. Let $\pi$ be any permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let
$$
  k_i=10^{i-1}\cdot2^{\min(\pi(i),n-1)}.
$$
The $k_i$ are distinct because they are divisible by distinct powers of $5$. We have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{10^{i-1}}{k_i}
    &=&\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2^{\min(\pi(i),n-1)}}\\
    &=&\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2^{\min(i,n-1)}}\\
    &=&\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2^i}\\
    &=&\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\\
    &=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}$$